# When we use % in CSS size property , what does that mean? In this case, grid items are allowed 100% of grid container but it is actually overflowing

Tags: css, css-grid

Here I allocated 100% height and width to all the images. But it actually overflows the grid container in height(40px). I actually want the images to cover up exactly 40px here.

HTML :

```
<div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-item" style="order : 1 ;">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
            <img src="E:\HTML AND CSS\images\fb.jpg" height="100%" width="100%">
            </a>
        </div> 
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.grid-container
{
    background : red;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto ;
    grid-template-rows:auto ;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: start;
}
.grid-item 
{
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid black;    
}
```

[image: the images are overflowing the required 40px area]

Comment: The `%` unit means "per cent of my parent", i.e. `height: 100%;` means "100 per cent of the height of my parent". But because there's an `a` also in the grid cell, now you have a total of the `a` tag's height plus an image that's exactly as tall as its parent is. Does `height: auto;` on the images not work? By the way, mixing external css and html attributes is a little strange.

Comment: no , auto does not work :( , I am actually learning CSS for the first time .

Comment: Could you paste your code into the question? That would make it easier to debug. Paste the html and css seperately, please.

Comment: I added the required codes .

Comment: Ok, can you take a look at https://codepen.io/isaactfa/pen/PoQPzzK and tell me what you want out to happen? I replace your images with some random ones, don't be confused.

Comment: height is not inherited by default unlike the width. `.grid-item` has no height and takes the value of the children.

Comment: Like in your codepen example , the grid items are overflowing the container area (the red colored container area) .

Comment: ok, this problem can be solved, if I used height as percentage in both grid item and container, but not with the pixels, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In CSS % moderator we use it when we want to get some measure from the parent element. As an example height is 40%, Which means 40 percent of height from the parent element. If the parent element height is 100cm, 40% height equals 40cm.

```
<div id="dev1" height=100cm>
 <div id="dev2" height=40%></div>
</div>
```

dev2 height will be 40cm.